# Which property of a circle or triangle show that $PT^2$ − $PU^2$ = $QT^2$ equation of concentric circle holds?

Tags: geometry, circles

Qn: If PT and PU are tangents from P to two concentric circles, with T on the
smaller, and if the segment PT meets the larger circle at Q, then $PT^2$ − $PU^2$ = $QT^2$ 
as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkalC.jpg)

Attempt1: Using formula on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3FuC.png) picture I get PU^2$ = $PQ*(2QT)$.
Which properties of circle or triangle can help me to prove equation above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: the equation can be written as

$$PT^2 − QT^2 = PU^2$$

and then

$$(PT +QT)(PT-QT)=PU^2$$

Now apply the rule explained on your second figure.

Answer (score 1):

You extend $PT$ so that it cuts the big circle in $Q$ and $Q'$. 
Let $O$ be center of our circles. You thus have $OT$ perpendicular to $QQ'$ so $$Q'T=QT$$
You then apply your relation (power of the point $P$):
$$PU^2 = PQ\times PQ' = (PT-QT)(PT+QT)=PT^2 - QT^2$$